# How to redirect previously requested page after login in java(JSP/Servlet)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, redirect, web-applications

In Java Web Application, I am trying to redirect to previously request page by the user after successful login.

Let us consider the scenario where after login of application it displays home page (home.jsp).
Home page have link of View Profile (profile.jsp).
If any user directly tries to access Profile page without login, it will redirect to login page, after login it should go to profile (profile.jsp).

How to code to go to directly profile page?

Comment: how about you do research, try to code something ask a question once you encounter a particular problem?

Comment: i tried to do it by setting the attribute of requested page but it is not working.

Comment: there are multiple ways to do this.. but as it is login/entitlements check -- most likely it is application-wide, try servlet filtering.. search for LoginFilter-- if you still have trouble finding it -- post your code and we can help

Answer (score 0):

use if condition if and check to successfull login if user login successfull than use  **RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/your_previous_page");

rd.forward(request,response);**
else send him back to login form page .

Comment: how to get previous page?